# "To the extent of" in this context

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Often it is suggested that the differences amount only to personal
>   preference. However, not all of the descriptions are equally able to
>   describe all observations of the real world. To the extent of these
>   differences, something more than "taste" or personal preference is
>   involved.

The "differences" above refers to differences between proposed theories (descriptions). Does "To the extent of these differences" here mean "as far as these differences are concerned" ?

Source: *What is centrifugal force?* by Robert P. Bauman, in The Physics Teacher, October 1980. [The first paragraph in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRoGE.jpg) link]

Comment: It's okay but no more. The text is heavy and wants an editor's tender loving care: "it is suggested" and "descriptions...describe."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression '... to the extent of/that ...' is usually used with the meaning ' ... to the point where ...', 'so far as to':

> You use expressions such as *to the extent of*, *to the extent that*,
>   or *to such an extent that* in order to emphasize that a situation has
>   reached a difficult, dangerous, or surprising
>   stage.[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-the-extent-of-that-to-such-an-extent-that-etc)].

- 'Why did we have to go to the extent of using tear gas and percussion grenades?' [[NYT; Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/go+to+the+extent)]
- "Our synagogues don't go to the extent of placing billboard ads for converts, but we do accept them," said Rabbi Jerome M. Epstein .... [[NYT; Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/go+to+the+extent)]
- "Part of our policy is clearly established: we wish to proceed with, to correctly use your word, very substantial disposal of public forest estate, which could go to the extent of all of it." [[The Guardian; Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/go+to+the+extent)]

Obviously, 'as far as' can be substituted in the above examples, and in the third one, the  'a difficult, dangerous, or surprising stage' is only loosely obeyed (and I'd say the example sounds at best clumsy).

But in the original, 'as far as these differences are concerned' is a far better replacement, and 'to the extent **that these differences are involved**' probably what was intended.

Answer (score -1):

You can understand it this way:

When the descriptions differ from each other to the extent of these differences, something more than "taste" or personal preference is involved.

That is:

When the descriptions differ from each other to the degree like these differences, something more than "taste" or personal preference is involved.

So "to the extent of these differences" doesn't mean "as far as these differences are concerned".

Because some descriptions are unable to describe all observations of the real world as precisely as other descriptions, both personal preference and ability are involved.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? "As far as sth is concerned" does not mean what it looks like but is to indicate the subject that you are talking or thinking about. It's almost like "as for" or "about". So "as far as sth is concerned" doesn't mean "to the extent of". Edwin Ashworth is wrong, saying "in the original, 'as far as these differences are concerned' is a far better replacement".

Comment: The Collins definition of "as far as sth is concerned": https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-far-as-something-is-concerned-where-something-is-concerned; the Cambridge definition: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concerned?q=as+far+as+sth+is+concerned.